# Call function when new result has been returned from API

Tags: python, api, events

There is an API that I am using from another company that returns the ID-s of the last 100 purchases that have been made in their website.

I have a function `change_status(purchase_id)` that I would like to call whenever a new purchase has been made. I know a workaround on how to do it, do a while True loop, keep an index `last_modified_id` for the last modified status of a purchase and loop all purchases from the latest to the earliest and stop once the current id is the same as `last_modified_id` and then put a sleeper for 10 seconds after each iteration.

Is there a better way on how to do it using events in python? Like calling the function `change_status(purchase_id)` when the result of that API has been changed. I have been searching around for a few days but could not find about about an event and an API. Any suggestion or idea helps. Posting what I have done is usually good in stackoverflow, but I don't have anything about events. The loop solution is totally different from the events solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to keep calling the API and watching for changes from the previous response, unless...

The API provider might have an option to call your API when something is updated on their side. It is a similar mechanism to push notifications. If they provide a method to do that, you can create an endpoint on your side to do whatever you need to do when a new purchase is made, and provide them the endpoint. However, as far as I know, most API providers do not do this, and the first method is your only option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, the API provider solution is not possible, but thank you for the answer. I will stick to the loop solution.